# join table with 2 FKs to one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a "2-person-team" model and a "Project" model. I want to create a join table so I can pair 2 people together on one project. But this idea seems weird:

```
User
:id

Project
:id

Team
:user_id_1
:user_id_2
:project_id
```

Is this a bad idea? I was thinking maybe just creating an `Assignment` table, so each `User` has one assignment to a project, but then there's no concept of a pair of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following schema

```
User
:id

Project
:id

Assignment
:user_id
:project_id
(create 1 row for each user in the project)
```

Example, view users for a project:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM User u
JOIN Assignment a ON a.user_id = u.id
JOIN Project p ON p.id = a.project_id
WHERE p.id = xxx;
```

Find a user's teammate on a project:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM User u
JOIN Assignment a ON a.user_id = u.id
JOIN Project p ON p.id = a.project_id
WHERE p.id = xxx AND u.id != yyy;
```

Comment: thank you, so I would just have to look up a user's assigned project and find their teammate from that?

Comment: I added a couple queries to show you how to use it. Please accept my answer as the correct one if it fits your needs